# Generic TypeScript Type for functions returning functions that replaces the ReturnType with the ReturnType of the returned function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, typescript-typings, redux-thunk

**Dear TypeScript-3-Gurus out there,**

can someone help my define a generic type `GuruMagic<T>` that does the following?

`T` is a function returning a function, e.g. this:

```
fetchUser(id: Id) => (dispatch: Dispatch) => Promise<boolean>
```

The generic type should then *replace* the `ReturnType`of `fetchUser`with the `ReturnType`of the returned function. Like this:

```
type dispatchedAction = GuruMagic<typeof fetchUser>;
// so that dispatchedAction === (id: Id) => Promise<boolean>
```

I know that I can apply `ReturnType` two times to get `Promise<boolean>`, but I don't know how to concat the original parameters (possibly multiple) with this return type. Is this even possible with TypeScript (3.x)?

**Other examples for clarity**

```
const f1 = (a: number, b: string) => () => a;
type guruF1 = GuruMagic<typeof f1>; // (a: number, b: string) => number

const f2 = () => (name: string) => (otherName: string) => name + otherName;
type guruF2 = GuruMagic<typeof f2>; // () => (otherName: string) => string
```

**Motivation**

Typesafe `Redux-Thunk`. When I `connect` a `react` component it would be great if I could just do this:

```
import { fetchUser } from './myActions';

interface IPropsOfMyComponent {
  fetchUser: GuruMagic<typeof fetchUser>;
}

// ... MyComponent Definition ...

connect<{}, IPropsOfMyComponent, {}>(null, { fetchUser })(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) and the generic argument-list manipulation powers introduced in TypeScript 3.0 via support for [tuple types in rest and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).  Here's one way to do it:

```
type GuruMagic<FF extends (...args: any[]) => (...args: any[]) => any> =
  FF extends (...args: infer A) => (...args: infer _) => infer R ? (...args: A) => R 
  : never;
```

So you infer the argument list for the function `FF` as `A`, and the return type of the return type of the function `FF` as `R`, and then return a new function from an argument list of `A` to `R`.   Does it work?

```
declare function fetchUser(id: Id): (dispatch: Dispatch) => Promise<boolean>
type dispatchedAction = GuruMagic<typeof fetchUser>;
// (id: Id) => Promise<boolean>

const f1 = (a: number, b: string) => () => a;
type guruF1 = GuruMagic<typeof f1>; 
// (a: number, b: string) => number

const f2 = () => (name: string) => (otherName: string) => name + otherName;
type guruF2 = GuruMagic<typeof f2>; 
// () => (otherName: string) => string
```

Yes it does!

I'm not 100% sure how you will use this type function in practice... the fact that it ignores the type of the arguments of the intermediate function worries me. If you try to actually implement a function of type `GuruMagic<T>` given a function of type `T` you will have a problem unless you supply the missing arguments somehow.  But maybe you're not even implementing a `GuruMagic<T>` given a `T`.  Anyway, that's your business, not mine.

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer! Works perfectly!
I'll only use this for redux-thunk-actions.  The intermediate arguments are ignored by me but used by redux itself when dispatching the action. When you pass an object as the `mapDispatchToProps` parameter as seen in the last line of my motivation-codeblock, redux basically converts it to `{ fetchUser: (...args) => dispatch(fetchUser(...args)) }`. So your `GuruMagic` type lets me infer the resulting type of this to type my components props more easily.
Thanks again! :)

PS: I may tweak your definition to only allow `ThunkActions`.

Comment: Perfect answer! I am curious though, is there a way to modify this to work with object of functions?

Comment: @PeterKottas what do you mean by "object of functions"?  What is the desired input and output type?  Possibly you just want to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).  If your question is more complex or you need more help than that you might want to make your own question.

Comment: @jcalz exactly the same example like the one mentioned here, I just have object where values are functions. And I want to use this GuruMagic on the that object instead of single function. The idea is it would give you type of that object therefore reducing copy paste code for all functions in that object. (you could also forget to map one function)

Comment: Actually this might work (afk) 
`type GuruObjectMagic<T> = {`
  `[P in keyof T]?: GuruMagic<typeof T[P]>;`
`}`

Comment: And it rly does, I've updated my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895824/mapped-object-types-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment91327065_46895824